# getImage() method undefined for the type ClipData.Item Java

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a custom gridView and I need to have an image and a text for the elements of the gridView.
I have this adapter for the gridView but I can't solve the error I have:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * 
 * @author manish.s
 *
 */
public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
 Context context;
 int layoutResourceId;
 ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();

 public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
   ArrayList<Item> data) {
  super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
  this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
  this.context = context;
  this.data = data;
 }

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View row = convertView;
  RecordHolder holder = null;

  if (row == null) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
   row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

   holder = new RecordHolder();
   holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
   holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
   row.setTag(holder);
  } else {
   holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
  }

  Item item = data.get(position);
  holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
  holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
  return row;

 }

 static class RecordHolder {
  TextView txtTitle;
  ImageView imageItem;

 }
}
```

The error I have is here:

```
holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
```

It says: The method item.getTitle (and also item.getImage) is undefined for the type ClipData.Item

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The error is very specific: The method you used isn't defined for ClipData.Item.

For the text try to use:

```
holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getText());
```

For the image it really depend on the way you built your Item.

Comment: my item is something like:
`gridArray.add(new Item(homeIcon,"Home"));` so basically a text and an image, the problem is that I haven't created an Item class, do I need to do that in order to customize it?

Comment: It could be a quick and good solution. You could also create 2 arrays, 1 of strings and one of Drawable and pass it it the adapter